# move_uploaded_file() fails to open stream due to invalid argument - PHP

Tags: php

I have this code to move my uploaded file to a specific directory:

```
if (isset($_FILES["image"]["name"])){ 
    if (!is_dir('pf/' . $uid)) {
        mkdir('pf/' . $uid);
        $large_image_location = "pf/" . $uid;
    }else {
        $large_image_location = "pf/" . $uid;
    }

    chmod ($large_image_location, 0777);
    move_uploaded_file("$userfile_tmp", "$large_image_location/$userfile_tmp");    

}
```

However that gives the following error:

```
( ! ) Warning: move_uploaded_file(pf/BfyhieniKJGGqTNm/C:\wamp\tmp\phpF08A.tmp) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\wamp\www\mingle\upload_dp.php on line 26
```

Any help on how to sort this out would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Something is definitely wrong with the path to your source file... Look at it... "pf/BfyhieniKJGGqTNm/C:\wamp\tmp\phpF08A.tmp"

Comment: What is the value of `$userfile_tmp`? Try and add `var_dump($userfile_tmp);` right before `move_uploaded_file()` and provide the output.

Comment: @BenediktOlek You already have it in the error my friend...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is 90% of your woes:

```
 move_uploaded_file("$userfile_tmp", "$large_image_location/$userfile_tmp");
```

You using the moved to path at the beginning of the upload path. Try:

```
move_uploaded_file("$userfile_tmp", "$large_image_location/".$_FILES['image']['name']);
```

That should work better.

Answer (score 2):

The error itself is pretty clear, `pf/BfyhieniKJGGqTNm/C:\wamp\tmp\phpF08A.tmp` is not a valid filename.

Don't change the contents of `$_FILES[n]['tmp_name']` (or `$userfile_tmp` for that matter), since it will always contain the full path to the uploaded file.

Comment: The code should simply read move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], ...) IMO